# VS2012 or IIS adding slashes to html output

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

Using VS2012 to build an HTML5 web site. Have DOCTYPE:HTML5 set for intellisense. I code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">` and it appears in browsers' view source and the W3C Validator as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />` with the trailing slash.

The page's doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Is this VS2012 or IIS or the browsers that appear to adding the trailing slash?

How can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Don't get you that's just closing the tag. Do you want to see a closing tag instead, and if so why?

Comment: I'm coding HTML5 not XHTML. My preference is to use the old HTML4 syntax, less characters to send over the wire. Same with img tags. They don't need a "/>" at the end any more. In any case, VS2012 shouldn't be altering my HTML code. It's what MS got a bad rep for years ago. Thought they had stopped that.

Comment: Sorry it's not something I can get excited about, unless I was the poor fool writing the parser, in which case this daft "improvement" to the spec would have simply irritated me. I find it no surprise at all that most didn't bother with it. A totally trivial "improvement", that would have required significant effort to implement.

Comment: VS2012 is also removing all non-ms vendor css properties such as background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#AFD828, #7FA914); and just leaving a single background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#AFD828, #7FA914);

Comment: Well as you say it's not the first time they've tried to impose some standard by fiat of their monopoly. Did find a similar question on here, but that was Rails with Haml, which I suspect isn't going to be a big help. :)